# ¿Por qué están cambiadas las escalas de los dos ejes Y de esta gráfica con matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Intento representar tres gráficos de línea, en uno solo, de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = yf.download('AAPL', start= '2016-1-1', end = '2021-3-5', column = 'Close')
df = df.drop(['Adj Close','High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'], axis=1 )
df['pct change'] = df['Close'].pct_change()
df.dropna(inplace=True)

def calculate_volatility(df):      
    #14 day volatility
    df['14_days_volatility'] = (df['pct change'].rolling(14).std())*100
    #Annualized volatility
    df['14_days_annualized_volatility'] = df['14_days_volatility'] *(251**0.5)
    # Average of the last 126 values of the annualized volatility.
    df['SMA_126_annualized_volatility'] = df['14_days_volatility'].rolling(126).mean()
    # Plot graphic
    # Create a figure and some x and y axes
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
    # Create a new axis. The X axis is invisible and the Y axis is displayed on the opposite side to the previous one.
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    # Create the objects to display on the ax1 and ax2 axes
    volatility_line = ax1.plot(df['14_days_annualized_volatility'], 'green', linestyle = '-', label = '14 days annualized vol.', lw=1.5)
    sma_line = ax1.plot(df['SMA_126_annualized_volatility'], 'blue', linestyle = '-', label = 'SMA 126 annualized vol.', lw=1.5)
    close_line = ax1.plot(df['Close'], 'red' , label = 'Close prices', lw=1.5)
    # Graph title
    plt.title = 'Historical evolution of prices and volatility.'
    # X and Y axis labels
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Annualized volatility', color ='black')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Close prices', color ='black')
    # Create a list with the three graphs
    plot_lines = volatility_line + sma_line + close_line
    # Create a list with the labels of each plot
    labels = [line.get_label() for line in plot_lines]
    # Include in the legend the list of plots and the labels of each plot
    ax1.legend (plot_lines, labels, loc = 'upper left', frameon = True, borderpad = 1)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.grid(False)
    plt.show
        
calculate_volatility(df)
```

[image: Plot]

Las etiquetas de los dos ejes Y, son correctas, pero no así las escalas. La escala del eje Y de la izquierda, debería ser la de el eje Y de la derecha, y viceversa.
¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?. Agradeceré ayuda

Answer (score 1):

En parte he solucinado el problema cambiando estas sentencias

```
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Closed prices', color ='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('Annualized volatility', color ='black')
```

Digo en parte,por que lo que yo quisiera es tener la escala 'Closed prices' a la derecha.

[image: Gráfico nuevo]

Me gustaría entender un poco mejor cómo posicionar los ejes a uno u otro lado.

Answer (score 0):

El código correcto sería:

```
# Plot graphic
# Create a figure and some x and y axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
# Create a new axis. The X axis is invisible and the Y axis is displayed on the opposite side to the previous one.
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
# Create the objects to display on the ax1 and ax2 axes
prices_line = ax1.plot(df_atr['Date'], df_atr[assest_name], 'green', linestyle = '-', label = '14 days annualized vol.', lw=1.5)
atr_line = ax2.plot(df_atr['Date'], df_atr['ATR'], 'blue', linestyle = '-', label = 'SMA 126 annualized vol.', lw=1.5)

# Graph title
plt.title = 'Historical evolution of prices and ATR of ' + assest_name
# X and Y axis labels
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Prices', color ='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('ATR', color ='black')
# Create a list with the two graphs
plot_lines = prices_line + atr_line  # se podrían añadir otras líneas con +...

# Create a list with the labels of each plot
#labels = line.get_label() 
labels = ['Precios', 'ATR']
for line in plot_lines:
    # Include in the legend the list of plots and the labels of each plot
    ax1.legend (plot_lines, labels, loc = 'upper left', frameon = True, borderpad = 1)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.grid(False)
    plt.show
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]